# Swift weather data from Openweathermap API?

Tags: json, swift, api, openweathermap

From `openweathermap api`, I am getting below response.

```
{
  "cod":"200",
  "message":0,
  "cnt":40,
  "list":[
     {
        "dt":1587643200,
        "main":{
           "temp":289.78,
           "feels_like":283.61,
           "temp_min":289.03,
           "temp_max":289.78,
           "pressure":1014,
           "sea_level":1014,
           "grnd_level":1010,
           "humidity":41,
           "temp_kf":0.75
        },
        "weather":[
           {
              "id":804,
              "main":"Clouds",
              "description":"overcast clouds",
              "icon":"04d"
           }
        ],
        "clouds":{
           "all":94
        },
        "wind":{
           "speed":6.75,
           "deg":2
        },
        "sys":{
           "pod":"d"
        },
        "dt_txt":"2020-04-23 12:00:00"
     },
     {
        "dt":1587654000,
        "main":{
           "temp":289.66,
           "feels_like":284.44,
           "temp_min":289.34,
           "temp_max":289.66,
           "pressure":1013,
           "sea_level":1013,
           "grnd_level":1009,
           "humidity":47,
           "temp_kf":0.32
        },
        "weather":[
           {
              "id":803,
              "main":"Clouds",
              "description":"broken clouds",
              "icon":"04d"
           }
        ],
        "clouds":{
           "all":67
        },
        "wind":{
           "speed":5.9,
           "deg":357
        },
        "sys":{
           "pod":"d"
        },
        "dt_txt":"2020-04-23 15:00:00"
     }
```

Then I write the code below to get wind data for any specific daytime(dt). I get the `jsonresponse` to the `Any` "list". But I can't get the wind data. I get the `error`

> "Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts".

Also, I can't understand how can I get the wind data for `dt=1587643200` and `dt=1587654000` separately.

```
                           if let list = jsonresponse["list"] as? Any {
                               let wind = list["wind"] as? [String : Any],
                               print(wind)
                           }
```

Comment: "list" is clearly an array so cast it as such or a much better solution altogether, research and use `Codable` instead

Comment: Hi, i casted "list" as [String : Any], but in this case i cant get the content of list. I also tried [String : [String:Any]].

Comment: I said array, not dictionary

Comment: Thanks , you are right it is an array. I casted "list" as an array and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a super simple example, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61286702/how-to-extract-value-from-json-object-with-dictionary-swift-4/61287020#61287020) is similar to your problem. I would like that you learn about [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) protocol to simplify and improve your code because of this way is super creepy.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?id=2885679&type=hour&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1")!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
            print("Error with the response, unexpected status code: \(String(describing: response))")
            return
    }

    guard let data = data else {
        return
    }

    guard let dictionaryObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
        return
    }

    guard let list = dictionaryObj["list"] as? [[String: Any]] else {

        return
    }

    if let first = list.first, let wind = first["wind"] {
        print(wind)
    }
}).resume()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it worked also, i will also look codable.

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to mark the question as answered, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone further needs help, I wrote a small code segment—using **Swift Codables**—to get this done.

Note that I'm using **Higher Order Functions in Swift** to filter & print the required values. You can follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ruchiram4/swift-higher-order-functions-4137f842d183) if you need to know more about how they work..

```
let urlNew = "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?id=2885679&type=hour&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1"
struct WeatherResponse: Codable {
    
    let message: String
    let cod: String
    let city_id: Int
    let calctime: Double
    let cnt: Int
    
    let list: [WeatherCompositeObject]
    
    struct WeatherCompositeObject: Codable {
        
        let main: WeatherMainObject
        let wind: WeatherWindObject
        let clouds: WeatherCloudObject
        let weather: [WeatherObject]
        let dt: Int
        
        struct WeatherMainObject: Codable {
            let temp: Double
            let humidity: Int
            //You can add the other parameters as needed here
        }
        
        struct WeatherWindObject: Codable {
            let speed: Double
            let deg: Double
        }
        
        struct WeatherCloudObject: Codable {
            let all: Int
        }
        
        struct WeatherObject: Codable {
            let id: Int
            let main: String
            let description: String
        }
    }
}

class ApiContentDownloader {

    func getCurrentWeather(url: String) {
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, urlResponse, error in
            
            let parser = ContentParser()
            let result = parser.parseData(data: data!)
            
            if let result = result {
                print("Weather: \(result.message)")
                print("DT values:  \(result.list.map({ $0.dt})) ")
                print("Wind values:  \(result.list.map({ $0.wind.speed})) ")
                print("Weather descriptions:  \(result.list.map({ $0.weather.map( {$0.description} )})) ")
            }
            else {
                print("Oops... Error occured")
            }
            
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
}

class ContentParser {
    
    func parseData(data: Data) -> WeatherResponse? {
       
        var result: WeatherResponse? = nil
        
        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherResponse.self, from: data)
            result = json
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        return result
    }
}

let downloader = ApiContentDownloader()
downloader.getCurrentWeather(url: urlNew)
```